RadioButton State Check in Android App Not Working as Expected, Showing Incorrect Error Message"
hi everyone i have problem this my code and i but the logd under see that , the problem is the zigzag true and fromfirst false and that normal to work but the code say select one from this two chooise and i say that one true and another one is false the app exit when i click on the button how to fix that
Not: the code was in java and i convert to kotlin in java he was work but here not work
(`_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.btn_Submit) as Button).setOnClickListener(
            View.OnClickListener
            // android.view.View.OnClickListener
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: click inside")
                try {
                    val SleepTime = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.SleepTime) as SeekBar
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: SleepTime $SleepTime")
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: SleepTime progress ${SleepTime.progress}")

                    val bluetooth = SharedPref.getInstance(this@MainActivity).getStringData("Bluetooth", "off")
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: bluetooth $bluetooth")

                    val otg = SharedPref.getInstance(this@MainActivity).getStringData("OTG", "off")
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: otg $otg")

                    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(SleepTime, "SleepTime")
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: intrinsics 1 ${Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(SleepTime, "SleepTime")}")

                    if (bluetooth.equals("on") || otg.equals("on")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: first if ${Intrinsics.areEqual(bluetooth, "on") || Intrinsics.areEqual(otg, "on")}")

                        if (!SleepTime.progress.equals(0)) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: sec if ${!Intrinsics.areEqual(SleepTime.progress, 0)}")

                            val PalsPerColumn = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.PalsPerColumn) as SeekBar
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: PalsPerColumn $PalsPerColumn")
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: PalsPerColumn progress ${PalsPerColumn.progress}")

                            Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(PalsPerColumn, "PalsPerColumn")
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: intrinsics 2 ${Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(PalsPerColumn, "PalsPerColumn")}")

                            val PalsPerRow = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.PalsPerRow) as SeekBar
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: PalsPerRow $PalsPerRow")
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: PalsPerRow progress ${PalsPerRow.progress}")

                            Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(PalsPerRow, "PalsPerRow")
                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: intrinsics 3 ${Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(PalsPerRow, "PalsPerRow")}")

                            if ((!PalsPerColumn.progress.equals(0)) && (!PalsPerRow.progress.equals(0))) {
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: third if ${(!Intrinsics.areEqual(PalsPerColumn.progress, 0)) && (!Intrinsics.areEqual(PalsPerRow.progress, 0))}")

                                val palsOrientation = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.palsOrientation) as RadioGroup
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: palsOrientation $palsOrientation")

                                Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(palsOrientation, "palsOrientation")
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: intrinsics 4 ${Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(palsOrientation, "palsOrientation")}")

                                val zigzag = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.zigzag) as RadioButton
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: zigzag $zigzag")
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: zigzag isChecked ${zigzag.isChecked}")

                                val fromFirst = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.fromFirst) as RadioButton
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: fromFirst $fromFirst")
                                Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked ${fromFirst.isChecked}")
                                
                                try {
                                    if (fromFirst.isChecked || zigzag.isChecked) {
                                        Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: orientation selected")
                                        if ((!fromFirst.isChecked) || (!zigzag.isChecked)) {
                                            Log.d(
                                                "TAG",
                                                "aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked ${fromFirst.isChecked}," +
                                                        " zigzag isChecked ${zigzag.isChecked}"
                                            )
                                            Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: orientation not selected")

                                            val errors =
                                                `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.errors) as TextView
                                            errors.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                            errors.text = "Please select one of Scan Orientations"

                                            return@OnClickListener
                                        }
                                        this@MainActivity.setWhichBtn("surface")
                                        this@MainActivity.checkBluetooth()

                                        val main =
                                            `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.main) as LinearLayout
                                        main.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                                        val setting =
                                            `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.setting) as LinearLayout
                                        setting.visibility = View.GONE

                                        return@OnClickListener
                                    }

                                    val errors = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.errors) as TextView
                                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: errors $errors")
                                    errors.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    errors.text = "Please select one of Scan Orientations"

                                    return@OnClickListener
                                }catch (e:Exception){
                                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: $e")
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        val errors3 = `_$_findCachedViewById`(R.id.errors) as TextView
                        Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: errors3 $errors3")
                        errors3.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        errors3.text = "All fields must be completed"
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: Bluetooth or OTG OFF")
                        Alerts.show_alert(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            getString(R.string.not_connected),
                            getString(R.string.choose_connection_method)
                        )
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Log.d("TAG", "aly listeners: Exception caught: $e")
                }
            })

this logd
2024-09-08 14:07:05.694  aly listeners: click inside
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: SleepTime
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: SleepTime progress 1
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: bluetooth on
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: otg off
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: intrinsics 1 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: first if true
2024-09-08 14:07:05.695  aly listeners: sec if true
2024-09-08 14:07:05.696  aly listeners: PalsPerColumn
2024-09-08 14:07:05.697  aly listeners: PalsPerColumn progress 2
2024-09-08 14:07:05.697  aly listeners: intrinsics 2 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:05.698  aly listeners: PalsPerRow
2024-09-08 14:07:05.698  aly listeners: PalsPerRow progress 2
2024-09-08 14:07:05.698  aly listeners: intrinsics 3 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:05.698  aly listeners: third if true
2024-09-08 14:07:05.699  aly listeners: palsOrientation
2024-09-08 14:07:05.699  aly listeners: intrinsics 4 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:05.700  aly listeners: zigzag
2024-09-08 14:07:05.700  aly listeners: zigzag isChecked true
2024-09-08 14:07:05.701  aly listeners: fromFirst
2024-09-08 14:07:05.701  aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked false
2024-09-08 14:07:05.701  aly listeners: orientation selected
2024-09-08 14:07:05.701  aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked false, zigzag isChecked true
2024-09-08 14:07:05.701  aly listeners: orientation not selected
2024-09-08 14:07:09.852  aly listeners: click inside
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: SleepTime
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: SleepTime progress 1
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: bluetooth on
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: otg off
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: intrinsics 1 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: first if true
2024-09-08 14:07:09.853  aly listeners: sec if true
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: PalsPerColumn
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: PalsPerColumn progress 2
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: intrinsics 2 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: PalsPerRow
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: PalsPerRow progress 2
2024-09-08 14:07:09.854  aly listeners: intrinsics 3 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:09.855  aly listeners: third if true
2024-09-08 14:07:09.855  aly listeners: palsOrientation
2024-09-08 14:07:09.855  aly listeners: intrinsics 4 kotlin.Unit
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: zigzag
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: zigzag isChecked true
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: fromFirst
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked false
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: orientation selected
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: fromFirst isChecked false, zigzag isChecked true
2024-09-08 14:07:09.856  aly listeners: orientation not selected
